# PDF Invoice - content forcing new page

Tags: magento-1.8, invoice, pdf, zend-framework

I customized my pdf invoice. I use graphics for header (logo and company address) and footer (company bank account information, contacts etc.). So my layout on the pdf looks something like this: [image]

As you can hopefully see. The text is cut where the red arrow points. Only if the amount of ordered products is high enough to force the pdf to create a second page, the invoice is correct.

Where exactly does the pdf manage the creation of new pages. Is there a possibility to define the maximum page height, so that in this case, all contents that would collide with the top border of the footer graphic, would force a next page?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a [guide](https://www.creare.co.uk/blog/magento/tips-for-modifying-magento-pdfs) for that.
You should check the Zend_Pdf_Page class.

Comment: I managed to achieve what I wanted. In the Abstract.php there are two entries like this 

`if ($this->y - $lineSpacing < 15) {
    $page = $this->newPage($pageSettings);
}` 

The higher the value, the sooner the new page gets created.

Comment: Link is broken :(